# Long-running thread process under ASP.NET + WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf, multithreading, iis-7

**Duplicate**
This is a close duplicate of [Dealing with a longer running process in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142698/dealing-with-a-longer-running-process-in-wcf). Please considering posting your answer to that one instead of this.

**Original Question**
I'm implementing the business layer of an application that must run some background processes at scheduled times. The business layer is made up of several WCF services all running under the same web application.

The idea is defining a set of 'tasks' that must be run at different times (eg. every 5 minutes, everyday at 23:00, etc). That wouldn't be hard to implement as a windows service, but the problem is, the tasks need access to data caches that are living in the services, so this 'scheduler' must run under the IIS context in order to access that data.

What I'm doing currently is using a custom ServiceHostFactory in one of the WCF services which spawns a child thread and returns. The child thread sleeps and wakes up every X minutes to see if there are scheduled tasks and executes them.
But I'm worried about IIS randomly killing my thread when it recycles the application pool or after some inactive time (eg. no activity on any of the WCF services, which listen  for requests from the presentation layer). The thread must run uninterrupted regardless of activity on the services. Is this really possible?

I have found [an article by someone doing the same thing](http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/67557.aspx), but his solution seems to be pinging the server from the child thread itself regularly. Hopefully there is a better solution.

Comment: This is a very close duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142698/dealing-with-a-longer-running-process-in-wcf. Please take a look at it and see if you agree with me.

Answer (score 1):

I have at some point implemented a Windows Service that would load a web page on a regular basis. The purpose of that was was that the site was hosting a Workflow Foundation runtime, and we wanted to ensure that the web application was brought back up after IIS recycling the application pool. Perhaps the same approach can be used in this case; have a service (or Scheduled Task in Windows; even simpler) run every x minutes and load a page that will check for tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a possibility to run either a Windows Service or place applications in the Windows Scheduler to execute methods in the WCF at certain times? Maybe use a BackgroundWorker inside the WCF. Another option would be for WCF to spawn other applications to do the business logic, passing the appropriate data, or pointers to the data in memory(unsafe).